# Does it make sense to define strongly measurable functions on a Polish space instead of a Banch space?

Tags: measure-theory, bochner-spaces

Does it make sense to define strongly measurable functions on a Polish space instead of a on Banach space?

Is there any book that deals with this topic?

Comment: Do you define strong measurability in the sense that it is the limit of simple functions?

Comment: yes, this is the definition I am dealing with